# Can't get semantics of this loop in macro expanding

Tags: scala

I'm experimenting with Scala [FastParsers](https://github.com/begeric/FastParsers/) library and I'm studying macro expanding of the following code:

```
val trueValue = "true".toCharArray
val falseValue = "false".toCharArray

object KParser1 {
  import fastparsers.framework.implementations.FastParsersCharArray._

  val kparser = FastParsersCharArray {
    def func1: Parser[Any] = func1 | falseValue
  }
}
```

Whole expanding is [there](https://gist.github.com/Kakadu/0b5aa7118fcf17f21391) but a piece of code from there really bothers me

```
while$2() {
  if (inputpos$macro$2.$less(inputsize$macro$3).$amp$amp(input$macro$1(inputpos$macro$2).$eq$eq(' ').$bar$bar(input$macro$1(inputpos$macro$2).$eq$eq('\t')).$bar$bar(input$macro$1(inputpos$macro$2).$eq$eq('\n')).$bar$bar(input$macro$1(inputpos$macro$2).$eq$eq('\r'))))
  {
     inputpos$macro$2 = inputpos$macro$2.$plus(1);
     while$2()
  }
  else
     ()
};
```

It looks like the code which skips whitespace from input stream but I can't infer what exactly is `while$2`: is it declared there as `Unit => Unit` and called automatically or is it some predefined function with type `Unit => Any => Any`?

Comment: `while$2` looks like some loop implementation detail according to [this mail list discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-language/jmIouhGYLRg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a loop. Compare:

```
scala> while (!done) println("working")
[[syntax trees at end of                     typer]] // <console>
package $line5 {
  object $read extends scala.AnyRef {
    def <init>(): $line5.$read.type = {
      $read.super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    object $iw extends scala.AnyRef {
      def <init>(): type = {
        $iw.super.<init>();
        ()
      };
      import $line4.$read.$iw.$iw.done;
      object $iw extends scala.AnyRef {
        def <init>(): type = {
          $iw.super.<init>();
          ()
        };
        private[this] val res0: Unit = while$1(){
          if ($line4.$read.$iw.$iw.done.unary_!)
            {
              scala.this.Predef.println("working");
              while$1()
            }
          else
            ()
        };
        <stable> <accessor> def res0: Unit = $iw.this.res0
      }
    }
  }
}
```